# Does appending a hash of a timestamp to a randomly generated string make it less secure?

Tags: authentication, cryptography, session-management

I have the following code for generating session tokens:

```
binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(16)) + hashlib.md5(str(time.time())).hexdigest()
```

which converts the randomly generated 16 bytes suitable for use to hex format and appends a hash of the current timestamp.

Does appending the timestamp make it any less secure (against say, brute force attacks) than having just the randomly generated bytes?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the timestamp or even some constant string does not make the preceding random string less predictable by itself. But it might be if the attacker gets side information like the total length of the compressed string because in this case the less random part can be used to infer information about the random part. See for example the [CRIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRIME) and 
[BREACH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BREACH_(security_exploit)) attacks.

Comment: in those attacks, the compression is coming from the HTTPS and SPDY protocols. what compression are you referring to in this case?

Comment: @Transcendence: I refer to the compression you might use or not in your not fully known use case. If for example you would include such tokens inside the HTTP body and you use HTTP compression then attacks similar to BREACH could apply.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the random value was generated.

Take a look for example at Microsoft's [CryptGenRandom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptGenRandom#Method_of_operation) function. It uses many sources for the entropy and one of those sources is the current time. When you include the current time you are taking away that part of the entropy.

There are many good entropy sources left for that random value and the current time adds very little entropy anyway but yes: you did make the random value slightly less secure.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, all your cookie string should be a random one. The MD5 of timestamp is technically random but it can be reversed to actual timestamp.

Based on the timestamp in the cookie one can use it to mount any other suitable attack, for example try to break other weak mechanisms.

This is because such usage is not any way standard (as it's just used in some way in some custom software), therefore if there's no standardized usage of it then should not be used. And I think it can't be standardized because there's no reason in doing so.